# How to display username on screen after login?

Tags: java, android

I have a class called accountinfo and I want to display the username after the user logs in.

```
 public class accountinfo extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView name;
TextView nameTV;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accountinfo);


    nameTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

    name=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

    nameTV.setText("Welcome " + name);



  }
}
```

This returns "Welcome null"

Email is the username stored on database

Comment: where is a logic of fetching data from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If login successfull, you can save data via sharedpreferences. Save "name" to your shared preferences and then retrieve it. Sure. it's easy. Just take a look

Put this at login activity

```
userName = edtName.getText().toString();
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
              "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
prefs.edit().putString("name",userName).apply();
```

And then you need to retrive data from sharedpreferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = pres.getString("name", "");
```

So you can send any data with easily.

Comment: replace edtName with nameTV.

Answer (score 1):

Use `name.getText().toString()`. At `onClick(View v)`, not `onCreate()`, after calling `loginbutton.setonclicklistener(this)` in `oncreate()` because the user cannot enter text before `onCreate()` ends.

And to allow user to enter his/her info, it is better to use **EditText** instead of **TextView**.

E.g.

```
public class accountinfo extends AppCompatActivity implements Button.onClickListener
{
  EditText name;
  TextView nameTV;
  Button loginButton;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_accountinfo); 
    nameTV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email); 
     loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

    @override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name.getText().toString())){
         nameTV.setText("Welcome " + name.getText().toString());
    }
  }
}
```

And `activity_accountinfo.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="welcome"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/email"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="log in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If the current code is giving "Welcome null", this will throw a `NullPointerException`, unless they just happened to have set the `text` attribute on the `email` `TextView` to `"null"`.

Comment: The program throws an error on the if statement in the onCreate method.

Comment: Edited. To use gettext.tostring.

Answer (score 1):

use put extra

in loginclass:

```
LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {

     //your text do u want pass
    String s=edit.getText().toString();

    Intent ii=new Intent(LoginActivity.this, newclass.class);
    ii.putExtra("name", s);
    startActivity(ii);
}
```

in second class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intent);
    Textv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    Intent iin= getIntent();
    Bundle b = iin.getExtras();

    if(b!=null)
    {
        String j =(String) b.get("name");
    }
}
```